# Bash Arithmetic Gives Wrong Answer

Tags: bash, math, overflow, echo

Can anyone explain why this does not give the correct answer? Does it have something to do with an overflow?

```
$ echo $(((729669216169173060 * 256) + 73))
2327878602212787273
```

But the answer should be `186795319339308303433`.

Answer (score 7):

bash arithmetic can hold integers as 64-bit signed long int. Which means maximum allowed number is:

```
9223372036854775807
```

If you do:

```
echo $((9223372036854775807 + 1))
-9223372036854775808
```

So overflow occurs. And you are trying:

```
729669216169173060 * 256
186795319339308303360
```

Which is much more than `9223372036854775807`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the bash calculator, `bc`:

```
$ bc <<<"(729669216169173060 * 256) + 73"
186795319339308303433
```

As you have guessed, your problem relates to overflow. `bc` supports arbitrary precision numbers, so can deal with your calculation.

Answer (score 1):

You're incurring in overflow, use `bc` for calculations that require big numbers:

```
bc <<< "(729669216169173060 * 256) + 73"
```

Prints:

```
186795319339308303433
```